# twitter bootstrap tabs and getBBox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, svg, d3.js

Consider the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/emepyc/gVNRc/

```
 <body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#plot" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="plot" class="tab-pane">
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

When the "plot" div element is under the bootstrap control, the bbox is wrongly reported as:
SVGRect {height: 0, width: 0, y: 0, x: 0}

But moving the div element outside...

```
 <body>
    <div id="plot">
    </div>
 </body>
```

... the bbox is correctly reported as:
SVGRect {height: 146, width: 848, y: 180, x: 56}

Does anybody know what is going on here?

M;

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like this conversation has been going on elsewhere...
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/dW_pt5vs7kE

And indeed, it has already been mentioned about how the svg will appear correctly if it is initialized inside a `tab-pane` div if the tab-pane is the first `active` tab-pane.

http://jsfiddle.net/SzVrs/8/

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#plot" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#plotThickens" data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="plot" class="tab-pane active"></div>
    <div id="plotThickens" class="tab-pane">
        <div class="alert">
          <p>The plot thickens!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But what to do if the svg element is not inside the first `active` tab?

Here is one approach: remove the svg element, 
and rebuild it when clicking the href of the bootstrap nav.

http://jsfiddle.net/3LhtX/10/

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
   $('svg').remove();
   var svg = plot();
   BB(svg);
 });
```

Comment: Yes, this can be a workaround. But having to recreate a heavy svg every time the tag gets active is not an ideal solution.